# How to get from PrintableString to GeneralString in ASN.1 Golang?

Tags: go, asn.1, der

I have Golang structure:

```
type Dog struct {
    Name string
    UUID *big.Int
}
```

Then I asn1.Marshal it:

```
dog := Dog{Name: "Rex", UUID: new(big.Int).SetBytes([]byte{0, 0, 7})}
dogAsn, _ := asn1.Marshal(dog)
```

When I look at the ASN.1 structure of "dogAsn" (using dumpasn1 Linux utility)I see:

```
SEQUENCE {
    PrintableString 'Rex'
    INTEGER
        00 00 00 07
    }
```

I wish NOT to have "PrintableString" there, but instead "GeneralString":

(Desired output):

```
SEQUENCE {
    GeneralString 'Rex'
    INTEGER
        00 00 00 07
}
```

Adding `asn1:"tag:27"` to the "Name" field:

```
type Dog struct {
    Name string `asn1:"tag:27"`
    ...
}
```

Doesn't solve my issue. Any good ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*> **Solution has been found!***

==============================

If you need to create an ASN.1 GeneralString in a Golang, then do this:

1.

```
type Dog struct {
    Name asn1.RawValue // previously was "string"
    UUID *big.Int
}
```

2. 

```
dogGeneralStr := asn1.RawValue{Tag: asn1.TagGeneralString, Bytes: []byte("Rex")}
dog := Dog{Name: dogGeneralStr, UUID: new(big.Int).SetBytes([]byte{0, 0,7})}
dogAsn, _ := asn1.Marshal(dog)
```

3. SEQUENCE {
   GeneralString 'Rex'
   INTEGER
   00 00 00 07
   }

P.S Then inside your program, whenever you need this dog.Name in a []byte or string form you just do: dogGeneralStr.Bytes or string(dogGeneralStr.Bytes) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the built in library. The [marshalling logic](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.1:src/encoding/asn1/marshal.go;l=563) allows you to pick between `IA5String`, `PrintableString`, `NumericString` or `UTF8String`.

I found an alternative ASN.1 library: https://github.com/Logicalis/asn1
But is is no longer maintained and also encodes all [strings as `OctetString`](https://github.com/Logicalis/asn1/blob/master/encode.go#L105)

So you best bet is to copy the source code of `encoding/asn1` and add a custom tag to indicate `GeneralString` while encoding. Perhaps you could even make a PR out of it.